# linqpad In parent script Util.complile and run async sub-scrip hangs on execution

Tags: linqpad

I'm trying to call a linqpad script from another linqpad script but it tends to just hand.   The subscript is an async process so im not sure what im doing wrong.  I dont get any Dumps out either so Im not sure what is going on.  I do know the subscript does work as it runs fine by it self.

```
void Main()
{
var testPass = new TestObject();

var compiledQuery = Util.Compile(@".\TestSubScript.linq", false);
var retVal = compiledQuery.Run(QueryResultFormat.Html, testPass);
retVal.AsString();

}
```

And the subscript looks like the following

```
async Task Main(TestObject input)
{
"In sub script".Dump();
// bunch of asnyc calls
}
```

Comment: Do you get the same result if you try the latest beta? Also, you will need to mark TestObject as [Serializable] (although you should get an error if you don't).

Comment: yes TestObject is marked as [Serializable]  and lives in the my extensions  script, and I'm able to pass values to my function.

I'll give the beta a new try.  Its this still marked as beta functionality ?  I couldnt seem to find any  documentation on what is beta  or what is supported

Comment: beside the stack overflow on all of the extensions and the website resource page on how to use the  Util.Run

Answer (score 0):

I had a Util.ReadLine().  I had forgotten about a Util.ReadLine() I was using to ask for details to run the query against.  Once I passed in the correct data object to use the code I had set to bypass this Util.ReadLine()   the script worked as intended.